# Parsing and Saving FpML data to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, fpml

I am working with FpML messages and looking to parse them and save them to SQL Server,  I have the xsd's and I'm using version 5.5.  I have generated the c# entities and most of the data (apart from the Product) is deserializing to the c# entities.

The next part I'm going to work on is saving the data to SQL server.  I could "hand crank" all the tables we need, which will take a while - I was wondering whether there's a tool out there for building the database objects from the XSD?